# When setting buttons opacity, all controls opacities are changed

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm using the C# under Windows 8. When I run

```
cancelButton.Opacity = 0.5;
```

All controls on the screen become 50% transparent.

If I run

```
cancelButton.Opacity = 0;
```

All controls disappear, likewise if I run

```
cancelButton.Opacity = 1;
```

Everything is visible, **including** the button. I have zero ideas as to what is going on.

Comment: Can you share your XAML and a little more code? Without it it's impossible to diagnose.